# My Chrome Devtools Not Show Debugging Info

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools

My device is detected, also I can click inspect on App I need to. But After I click it shows nothing.
I already try another device but still cannot. But if I use another laptop, it can

[image: chrome://inspect]

[image]

Comment: Can you specify which device/OS works and which doesn't?

Comment: @MorrisonChang the both os is using mac os catalina. The different is google chrome, version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) is working but my version Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit) not working.

I also try with Windows using latest chrome, it's also not working